# DBT - get a ref model config variables inside a macro

Tags: macros, jinja2, config, dbt

I am using macros to automate and make generic DBT incremental procedures.

##### Problem:

I try to get some config-variables from a model i use as a ref in another model. for each of my models i keep a `timestamp_column` in  config.
I want to be able to get the `timestamp_column` value from config whenever i need. I didn't find any proper way to do so.

##### Code Example:

for example in my _models.yml:

```
  - name: L0__game_runs
    config:
      materialized: incremental
      time_interval: hour
      timestamp_column: time_started

  - name: L1__drafts
    config:
      materialized: incremental
      time_interval: hour
      timestamp_column: created_at
```

The`L1__drafts` model query is referring `L0__game_runs` like:

```
with
    {% if is_incremental() %}
        {% set self_max_timestamp = get_table_max_timestamp(this) %}
         drafts as {{ (generate_source_query(ref('L0__game_runs'), self_max_timestamp)) }}
    {% else %}
          drafts as (select * from {{ ref('L0__game_runs') }}),
      {% endif %}
    
    <REST OF SQL COMES HERE...>
```

`generate_source_query.sql` macro:

```
{% macro generate_source_query(source_model, self_max_timestamp) %}
    {%- set source_timestamp_column = source_model.get('timestamp_column') -%}
    <REST OF MACRO COMES HERE...> 
{% endmacro %}
```

but `source_timestamp_column`return empty string result. didn't find any other way to fix it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, i found a way to solve it - using the [DBT graph context](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/graph) which get all DBT models configs (and more).

I wrote a macro to retrieve a ref model config values. its a bit naive but it good enough for me right now:

```
{% macro get_model_config_values(model_ref) %}
    {%- set table_name = model_ref.identifier -%}

    {% for node in graph.nodes.values() %}
        {%- set model_name = node.unique_id.split('.')[-1] -%}
        {%- if table_name == model_name -%}
            {%- set model_config = node.config -%}
            {{ return(model_config) }}
        {%- endif -%}
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbled upon the same issue, you can achieve the same using a bit more concise grammar:

```
{% macro get_model(relation) -%}
    {% for node in graph.nodes.values()
        | selectattr("resource_type", "equalto", "model")
        | selectattr("name", "equalto", relation.identifier) %}
        {% do return(node) %}
    {% endfor %}
{%- endmacro %}
```